# In electron, why can I not access DOM elements from the renderer thread?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have the most basic example of an Electron app, with an index.html that has

```
<span id="foo"></span>
```

and also includes `renderer.js` via

```
<script src="./renderer.js"></script>
```

The problem is, when I try to change my DOM element from renderer.js:

```
var element = document.getElementById("foo")
console.log({element});
element.innerText = "123";
```

I get this error, and "element" is null:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerText')
```

From my understanding, I'm not even using Electron features, I'm just using features that I could use in Chrome as well, so I don't get why this simple example won't work.

Comment: is that your whole renderer.js? try putting that in window.onload

Comment: Your HTML `<script>` tag for your `renderer.js` file is best included **after** your closing `</body>` tag **else** you will need to add [`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) within your `<script>` tag **or** use [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) within your `renderer.js` script when loaded inside your HTML `<head>` tag.